# ¿Como puedo ver mi clave de usuario sa? SQL SERVER 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

Puedo logearme las credenciales están pero no quiero cambiar el password ni detener algún servicio de sqlserver, será posbile poder ver la clave?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. No se entiende nada de tu pregunta. ¿Dónde quieres ver el password (clave)? Si no tienes la clave de SA, mucho me temo que aquí no podamos ayudarte a obtenerla. Saludos

Comment: Creo que no se puede, tendrás que cambiarla. A menos que hayan scripts, u otros sistemas que estén usando ese usuario. Si es así, podrías mirar en la fuente de alguno de los scripts, o en los archivos de config de los otros sistemas.

Answer (score 2):

**No es posible consultar la clave del usuario SA** o de ningún otro usuario en SQL Server.

Si tienes acceso con otro usuario que tenga privilegios de administrador, puedes cambiarla, pero no puedes ver la clave que tiene actualmente.

SQL Server almacena un *hash* derivado de la contraseña, que puedes consultar en  la DMV [`sys.sql_logins`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-logins-transact-sql) en la base de datos `master` del servidor.

Puedes verlo con la consulta:

```
select password_hash from master.sys.sql_logins where name = 'sa';
```

La documentación dice, sobre esta columna:

> Hash de la contraseña de inicio de sesión de SQL. A partir de SQL Server 2012 (11.x), la información de la contraseña almacenada se calcula con las funciones SHA-512 de la contraseña salada. (SIC)

Te puedes informar más sobre *contraseñas con sal* en el artículo [_Sal (criptografía)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sal_(criptograf%C3%ADa)) en la Wikipedia.